# Online resource to get expense ratios for mutual funds, index funds & ETFs?

Tags: mutual-funds, etf, index-fund, expense-ratio

Every article that deals with purchasing ETFs and index funds talks about *expense ratio*, but they usually don't show how to get it for an arbitrary fund.

So I'm curious, is there an online resource (independent of the funds that it sells) that allows to get an *expense ratio* for an ETF, index fund or a mutual fund by its stock/ticker symbol?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the answer from the horse's mouth, go to the website of the ETF or mutual find, and the expense ratio will be listed there, both on the "Important Information" part of the front page, as well as in the .pdf file that you click on to download the Prospectus.  Oh wait, you don't want to go the fund's website at all, just to a query site where you type in something like VFINX. hit SEARCH, and out pops the expense ratio for the Vanguard S&P 500 Index Fund? Well, have you considered MorningStar?

Comment: Yep, I guess. I just thought that it would be nice/handy to have it done in one location. (For instance, I was hoping that `Google Finance` does it, but I couldn't find it there.)